# Ruby on Rails css background-image not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use all of these:

```
1. body{ background-image: url('example.png') background-repeat: repeat;
2. body{ background-image: url('assets/example.png') background-repeat: repeat;
3. body{ background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'example.png') background-repeat: repeat;
4. body{ background-image: image-url(<%= asset_path 'example.png' %>) background-repeat: repeat;
5. body{ background-image: image-url('example.png') background-repeat:repeat;
6. body{ background-image: image-url('assets/example.png') background-repeat:repeat;

run assets:precompile
```

not working all, how to solve this problem, why not working?

Comment: what is the extension of the css file ?

Answer (score 1):

Number 5 is closest to the correct syntax. Is it because you're not terminating your first CSS rule with a semi-colon?

```
body{ 
  background-image: image-url('example.png');
  background-repeat:repeat;
}
```

That should work - note the semi-colon at the end of the background-image line.

Alternatively, merge them into a single rule:

```
body{ 
  background: image-url('example.png') repeat;
}
```